# How to make html call a javascript function from an external js file, in Django environment

Tags: javascript, html, django, alert, external

I am developing an app with Django.
I want an alert window pops up as soon as the user lands on a certain HTML page.

The javascript function that makes the window pop up is called `funprova`
and this function is stored inside a js file called `prova.js`, at the path

> static/js/prova.js

I want HTML call this function.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the external javascript file at path

> static/js/prova.js

insert

```
function funprova() {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box from remote js file!!");
    }
```

In the HTML page that has to pop up the window, before of the closing `</body>` tag, insert

```
{% load static %}

<script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/prova.js" %}></script>
<script> funprova() </script>
```

**Note**: You have to call javascript in two differents script tags, because in the former you make the call to a function stored an external file, while in the latter you call a function that was already imported into the HTML file environment.

**Note**: It is better to insert the `{% load static %}` Django tag at the very top of your HTML page, before the  HTML tag.