# How to write conditional validation using clean method in django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

Looking for help in finding logic for the model validation using the clean method.
what I need is either account_number AND bank_account_ifsc should be present  or (payee_vpa) should be present if currency is 'INR when post request is sent.

```
Models.py
class Order(models.Model):
    account_number = 
    models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,null=True,default=None)
    bank_account_ifsc = 
    models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True,null=True,default=None)
    payee_vpa = 
    models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True,default=None)
    def clean(self):
         if self.currency=='INR':
            if None in (self.account_number and 
            self.bank_account_ifsc) and not self.payee_vpa:
                raise ValidationError(_('payee_vpa is reqired')) 
            elif None in self.payee_vpa and not 
            (self.bank_account_ifsc and self.account_number):
                raise ValidationError(_('account_number and 
                                   bank_account_ifsc is reqired'))
serializers.py
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
     instance = Order(**attrs)
     instance.clean()
     return attrs
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

views.py
serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(): 
            serializer.save()
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57988547/how-to-make-html-call-a-javascript-function-from-an-external-js-file-in-django

Comment: where do you want to call it. I mean for what event

Comment: @shaswatkumar I just need to call this function to send a message about the successful event to a 3rd party  application.